# Does the Torah discuss aliens?

Tags: gentiles, animals, outer-space

1. Does the Torah discuss extra-terrestrial life and/or civilizations?
2. Do any Torah sources exist which discuss what these hypothetical beings would be like and their status/nature? (eg. Would they be similar to gentiles vis-à-vis their obligation in the *[Sheva Mitzvot Bnei Noach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah)*?)

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2009/09/r-david-nieto-matteh-dan.html

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43835

Comment: There is a great article by Norman Lamm in the book 'Challenges' about aliens

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Devorah and Barak's song (upon defeating Sisra), part of the song went as follows ([Shoftim 5:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15813#v523)):

> 'Curse you Meroz,' said the messenger of the Lord, 'curse you bitterly (you) inhabitants thereof,' because they came not to the aid of the Lord, to the aid of the Lord against the mighty.

The Talmud ([Mo'ed Kattan 16A](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1504&size=1) - [English on page 59 here](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Moed_Katan.pdf)) brings two opinions of who or what Meroz is. According to one of the opinions, Meroz is the name of a star. So Devorah and Barak are cursing the inhabitants of a star (i.e. aliens) for not coming to their aid in battle.

According to [here](http://www.interinclusion.org/inspirations/suspected-alien-life/):

> Hasdai Crescas, the great medieval Jewish philosopher, evoked the words of Psalm 19:2: “The heaven [or skies] declare the glory of God….” The rich cosmic landscape with all of its created wonders, is a testament to the artistry of its Creator...Crescas’ classic work, Ohr Hashem, originally published in Ferrara, Italy in 1555, contains an entire chapter where he maintains that the possibility of life on other planets is not in conflict with Jewish belief and Torah sources.

and from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112878/jewish/Aviation-and-Space.htm#footnote54a112878):

> Rabbi Chisdai Kerashkash, in his book Ohr Hashem (4, 5) explains that the possibility of extra-terrestrial life is not negated anywhere in Torah sources. The Sefer HaIkarim, on the other hand, quoted in Sefer HaBrit (1-3, 4), is of the opinion that there is no life on the stars and planets. The Sefer HaBrit himself argues, and agrees with Rabbi Chisdai. Similarly, the Chidah in Petach Einayim (on Tosafot, Menachot, 37a) is of the opinion that such life does exist.

Here is a [link to the Ohr Hashem](http://hebrewbooks.org/22063). According to the article by Aryeh Kaplan brought [Adam's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9197/does-the-torah-discuss-aliens/9204#9204), it is [Ma'amar 4, Drush 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22063&st=&pgnum=401).

Here is a [link to the Chidah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40655&st=&pgnum=219), (but he seems to be discussing two-headed sub-terrestrial human life.)

Here is the Sefer Habrit [(Part 1, Ma'amar 3, Chapter 4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43670&st=&pgnum=50). Please learn it, since I'm not sure I understood it correctly, but it appears he says that while life may exist, it will not be life we are familiar with. This is because the conditions are different there than they are here on earth. He compares this to sea-life. The Talmud says that everything that exists on dry land exists in the sea as well, but they are not exactly the same form. The ones in the sea may parallel the ones on dry land, but they're different because they live in a different environment.

He continues that it is impossible that there will be human-like aliens with free will, although they might have intellectual capabilities. According to Torah, only man was created with free will, not any creature lower (e.g. animals) or higher (e.g. angels) than  him.

[The Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112878/jewish/Aviation-and-Space.htm#112887) (see [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112878/jewish/Aviation-and-Space.htm#112887) and [here](http://www.interinclusion.org/inspirations/suspected-alien-life/)) said that “One who declares that there is no life besides on earth is limiting the Creator’s abilities.” And encouraged Professor Velvel Green to continue his work in this area.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe maintains that while life may exist on other planets, intelligent extraterrestrial beings with free choice do not exist. He appears to be differentiating between the capacity for intellect (a single trait) and an intelligent life form (the whole human package). [This may also be a result of a less than perfect translation]

Much like there are animals that can do things that are considered to be human traits, such as speak and use tools, so too there are non-human beings that have intellectual capacities. It is even possible that these non-human beings can surpass human capabilities. Angels, for example, have more intellectual capacities than humans (Maimonides Hilchot Yesodei Hatorah 3:9). However, free choice is a uniquely human capability that sets us apart from the the rest of creation. Free choice, according to Torah, is defining quality of intelligent life.

Free choice is only possible because G-d gave us the Torah. Without free choice, observing Torah and Mitzvot would be a sham. Therefore, when G-d gave us commandments, he gave with it the ability to truly choose whether to do them or not. It is because of the Torah that we have free choice. Since the Torah was only given to the Jewish people here on earth, we must say that any extra-terrestrial being does not have free will.

Civilized Societies are created by intelligent being with free choice. If aliens don't have free choice, they would not have civilizations.

See [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3012/jewish/Is-There-Life-on-Other-Planets.htm) for a summmary of the Lubavitcher Rebbe's view by Tzvi Freeman.

Comment: Love the research, but can you make a minor correction where you site the talmud.  The talmud is saying that Devorah asked for the star to help , 'not the inhabitants'...  However, if one wants to force that to mean aliens they can, but its not the pshat. Please make that clear.    (What stars can and can not do is a separate discussion)

Comment: @avi: I was referring to the second half of the passuk, "curse you bitterly (you) inhabitants thereof"

Comment: Menachem, great research! In your last paragraph you state, "...intelligent extraterrestrial beings with free choice do not exist (and therefore no extraterrestrial civilizations)." but this is not necessarily the case. As cited in Rabbi Kaplans article, intelligence does not require free will and therefore even according to the opinion that this life doesn't have free will it would still be possible to develop civilizations, etc. Can you address this?

Comment: @Adam: I'll preface all this by saying I'm not sure I have a complete answer. I will flesh out my answer to try and make it more clear. Here's a question. Do angels have civilizations? Angels have more intellect than people (Rambam Yesodei Hatorah 3:9). I would say no. Animals don't have civilizations. It seems to me that civilization is something uniquely human because of the conscious choice to live together for the greater good. According to Torah, free will is the defining, uniquely human characteristic that sets us apart.

Comment: Are you claiming that non-Jews don't have free choice?

Comment: If the inhabitants of Meroz do not have freewill then it was not their fault that they didn't come. So why the curse??

Comment: @DoubleAA: I think this was discusses somewhere on this site in relation to the Egyptians' punishment for the slavery in Egypt. My understanding is that non-Jews have free choice with regards to the commandments that they have to follow. There are statements in the Talmud that must be understood (such as that non-Jews are under the power of the Mazalot, while the Jews are not)

Comment: @DovF: good question. Poetic License?

Comment: @Menachem But even in the most limited perspective, regular non-Jews have to have free choice to convert as well. No?

Comment: @DoubleAA: One could argue that "Ger Shenitgayer", that converts are pre-selected, so to speak.

Comment: @Menachem But then couldn't aliens be pre-selected as well? I'm failing to see how the two are different.

Comment: @DoubleAA: That's another question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/can-an-alien-convert-to-judaism

Comment: @Menachem Whoops I'm getting confused which of these I'm reading.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Non-Jews have free choice because they too are subject to Torah commandments, namely The Seven Noahide Laws, which were also given specifically to the people here on Earth.

Comment: @Baruch How do you know they were 'given specifically to the people here on earth'?

Comment: @DoubleAA: The Seven Noahide Laws were given to Noah and his descendants, who were the only people on Earth after the flood.

Comment: @Baruch It seems your answer is based on a lot of specific implicit assumptions. You should clarify and source the ones you can there.

Comment: @DoubleAA: The only assumptions in [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17341/1274) are that aliens don't have free will, which is sourced, and that free will is required to be Jewish, which is in the same source. Whether Non-Jews have free will is a separate question.

Comment: Amazing answer and research. Shkoich! If you happen to find the Chida (where it is exactly) that would be a great find...

Comment: In regards to the cursing of Meroz...why would a seemingly intelligent species of life on another planet capable of some sort of travel to the Earth bother themselves in a Bronze Age conflict? For what purpose, why? If the the late Lubavitcher Rebbe was correct that since these aliens did not have a Torah, etc and therefore lacked free will...are we then saying that G-d told them to give the Israelites a lie that they would help and then back out on the deal(which denotes free will)? What is this? Cosmic puppetry? ...

Comment: ... Lastly, where is the physical evidence. Did Meroz leave something behind? Why is there no record of their language, what they looked like, etc? Why is there no record stating that Meroz is close to such and such planet or star? There may or may not be intelligent life on other worlds...but there is to date, no physical evidence.

Comment: @yaakovrowland, I think you misunderstand the point. Verse 20: "From heaven they fought; the stars from their courses fought against Sisera." This is the context where Meroz is a star.

Comment: [Not necessarily a proof.](http://astrotorah.weeklyshtikle.com/2010/01/gemaras-aliens-or-torah-ignorance.html)

Comment: "The Lubavitcher Rebbe maintains that while life may exist on other planets, intelligent extraterrestrial beings with free choice do not exist. " I dont think thats true,  I saw in a sicha תורת מנחם חנ"ז עמ' 172 that there is "absolute proof" that there is life on other planets, but the Torah was only given on earth

Comment: @B''HBi'ezra--BoruchHashem Do you have a link to the text online. Both hebrewbooks.org and lahak.org do not have that volume online.

Comment: @Menachem the reference to the sichos kodesh version is in my answer here

Answer (score 27):

To answer your question clearly,

1. Although the Pentateuch does not seem to make any mention of extraterrestrial life, some places in Nevi'im and Ketuvim may be understood to be making reference to Extraterrestrial life. One instance is in [Shoftim 5:23](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0705.htm#23),

   > 'Curse ye Meroz', said the angel of the LORD, 'Curse ye bitterly the inhabitants thereof, because they came not to the help of the LORD, to the help of the LORD against the mighty.'

   Meroz is identified in the Talmud ([Moed Kattan 16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=16&format=pdf)) as (according to one opinion) a star or celestial body,

   > ...מרוז איכא דאמרי גברא רבה הוה ואיכא דאמרי כוכבא הוה...

   Based on one understanding of this opinion's reading of the *pasuk* it would seem that Meroz is inhabited/contains a civilization who would be capable of aiding the Jewish people in battle.

   Various Kabbalistic works (whose translation and discussion are out of my scope) make mention of the possibility of extraterrestrial life as do a number of medieval Jewish philosophers. For more on this see below.
2. Regarding what the status of these being would be and their obligation in the *Sheva Mitzvot Bnei Noach*, *[Sefer Habrit](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43670&st=&pgnum=50)* tells us, 'we should not expect these beings to resemble life on our earth, just as life of the sea does not resemble that of the land' and it seems clear that they would not be obligated in the *Sheva Mitzvot Bnei Noach* being that they were not commanded in them and are not descendants of Noach.

---

[Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Kaplan) wrote a phenomenal piece on this topic which lays out all the sources and philosophical implications of extraterrestrial Life (ie. aliens) called "On Extraterrestrial Life" which was originally published in Intercom Magazine in 1972 and again published posthumously as part of "The Aryeh Kaplan Reader" ([here is a link to Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=bv5lmlmRmbwC&lpg=PP1&dq=aryeh%20kaplan&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and is available online [here](http://www.biblemysteries.com/library/ufos.htm).

I strongly recommend reading it if you are interested in this topic, but here is a basic synopsis of the 3 main opinoins:

- Rav Chasdai Crescas in his work, *[Or HaShem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22063&st=&pgnum=401)*, comes to the conclusion that there is nothing in Jewish theology to preclude extraterrestrial Life.
- Rav Yosef Albo disagrees with this concept and states that it is theologically impossible for extraterrestrial Life to exist.
- *[Sefer Habrit](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43670&st=&pgnum=50)* takes a middle road in stating that extraterrestrial Life certainly exists, but that it does not posses free will (although the beings may be intelligent). He adds that we should not expect these beings to resemble life on our earth, just as life of the sea does not resemble that of the land.

In the article Rabbi Kaplan lays out the foundations to answering your question by discussing the nature of free will and how it relates to these hypothetical extraterrestrial beings.

Comment: it seems like that sefer habris is talking about spiritual creations since hE SAys that it would be false to say theyre "וגשמיים" "physical

Answer (score 9):

Similar to several answers above: there was a Jewish biologist who consulted for NASA when they were concerned about viruses being brought back by astronauts and the like. He said he spoke with Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneurson, the 7th Lubavitcher Rebbe, about extraterrestrial life. The Rebbe said that sentient beings would be theologically problematic, but all other sorts of life forms were most certainly possible. "And don't say they can't exist, because then you're claiming there's something G-d can't do!"

Comment: You can read more about it in one of the links I have in my answer: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112878/jewish/Aviation-and-Space.htm#112887

Comment: The reason to not believe in them isnt because God _cant_ do it, but because he implied that he did not.

Comment: Source for the quote from R. Shneerson?

Answer (score 5):

Traditionally no, however a alien inclined reading of the Bible, could lead one to believe that the "Nephilim" (נְפִילִים) and "Anakim" (ענקים) might be aliens, or other races of humans. They are treated as goyim and not animals.

However, the alien life forms so far discovered by science all fall under the halachic category of 'non-existent' since they can not be seen with the naked eye :)

Comment: What do you mean by "They are treated as goyim and not animals."? What do you mean by: However, the alien life forms so far discovered by science all fall under the halachic category of 'non-existent' since they can not be seen with the naked eye? I am not aware of even the confirmation of the existence of extraterrestrial microorganisms.

Comment: I was answering the second question, saying that nephilim and anakim aliens if they existed would be treated like other goyim and expected to behave with certain standards and not like animals having no free will.

Answer (score 3):

The Sheva Mitzvot of Bnei Noach are for the decendants of Noach, so unless the aliens were first offspring of Noach and then moved to another planet, then no, aliens would not need to keep Sheva Mitzvot. If they are in a similar image to Noach, it might be a good idea to teach them the Sheva Mitzvot though :-P

Comment: Can they convert to Noahidism like non-Jews can convert to Judaism?  Also, can they convert to Judaism?

Answer (score 0):

I love the research you have done. I'm interested in the fact that my rabbi says that to believe in aliens is non-religious and goes against the Torah: I say it doesn't, because in many instances, such as in Ezekiel, it mentions some sort of, I'm assuming, beings in a craft telling to take measurements — and also in Enoch. And I do believe that in Song of Solomon it is written that he possessed a flying machine referred to as a "carpet", which is an *analogam*, as that term was used widely in the Middle East in those days to describe these flying machines.

Comment: While some of this post does serve as a partial answer to the question asked, so I'll leave it in place, it also contains a question, which belongs not here but (if anywhere) as a [new question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Anyway, welcome to the site; I hope you stick around and enjoy it. You might want to check out the [faq] and to register your account: both will allow you to enjoy the site's features better.

Answer (score 0):

BH

Yes, someone told me he saw the sources in Toras Menachem, but I didn't believe him, then he showed me.

I later tried to find it but was very difficult, but by searching key phrases I discovered it's in volume 57 page 172 http://www.halachabrura.org/agada/26shvuoteduyot.htm,

only thing is that volume is not anywhere online, but the original yiddush is in Sichos Kodesh, year 5729, volume 2 page 341, 7th section of that page [for some reason each page number is divided into many other pages]

Here's a free translation into English [you get what u pay for], the square and curly brackets are my own words, round brackets are in original text:

> BH
>
> "..which we had asked of him: one may ask, indeed, regarding what one
> might ponder, if there exist "life forms" [yitzurim] and "animals"
> [baalei chayim] on the stars etc..
>
> Which, this is all, in truth, has no concept that is relevent to Torah
> and Mitzvos; rather, one is strongly involved in tefilllin; in order
> that there should come another one who puts on teffilin...
>
> and through this which another will ask him, when he knows what to
> answer, then through this there will come by the other, that he should
> be a keeper of shabbos, or eating kosher, or putting on teffilin..
>
> [because of this], one can answer such a person:
>
> there is a gemara
>
> Ah, but why had he never heard of this?
>
> there is, in truth, two gemaras.
>
> one time in shavuos, which this is indeed a gemara that they indeed
> learn in yeshvios, and masechtas moed katan, which we indeed learn in
> the times of "between the boundaries" [bein mitzarim {the time that
> the sicha is being given, in shabbos chazon}]
>
> ...which indeed, we didn't write this in the gemara right after we
> "flew" on the moon; rather, the gemara, we had published hundreds of
> years prior, and it had been said {I guess "said" by word of mouth}
> even more hundreds of years before, and it had been spoken to Moshe
> from Sinai
>
> Which there in gemara, it says that at the time that Devorah had said
> the song regarding the war of Barack {obama?} and Sisra, she had said
> "Cursed be Meroz, cursed be it's inhabitants".
>
> Which there {in the gemara} there are 2 "ones who say", regarding what
> the translation of "Meroz" is.
>
> The first "One who says" says that Meroz is a name of a star, which
> the star was the Mazal of Sisra, and because of this, he {the star}
> didn't come to the help of Yisroel,
>
> and "its inhabitants" means these which "sit" on the star {sit or
> dwell, "Yoshev"...}
>
> And like Rashi himself brings (in
> Shoftim), both explanations {I assume it means the other of it being
> "a man" which wasn't mentioned here}, and Rashi brings there, the
> first explanation, that this is a star, and "its inhabitants" refer to
> those which sit on the star.
>
> Which the Giving of the Torah is indeed specifically here below, since
> the Adam [person] in this world is greater [lit. "more high"]
> than the "creations" on the stars
>
> And even though that Rabeinu Chananeil explains that "its inhabitants"
> are these stars which are around the star Meroz; nevertheless, there
> is indeed here many difficulties regarding the explanation of Rabeinu
> Chananeil.
>
> {The rest of the Sicha is missing}