# Where can I get Aryeh Kaplan’s מורה אור?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation

The author Aryeh Kaplan was well known for writing many scholarly English books about Judaism. After his death, several of his unpublished manuscripts were eventually published. One of them was a Hebrew manuscript. This was published under the name [Moreh Ohr, מורה אור.](http://www.nehora.com/products/Moreh-Ohr-%252d-Rabbi-Aryeh-Kaplan-----%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%252d%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%9F%252d%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8%252d%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%94.html)

It seems to be out of stock. Any suggestions, where to get it *specifically, for purchase.* In any country too - Israel, USA etc. online, or scanned in PDF?

p.s.

I’ve contacted quite a few booksellers and the like which I could get my hands on - to no avail. Also, if it is in your possession, consider adding to to Hebrewbooks and the like possibly - Googlebooks doesn’t seem to want to release it to the public.

<sub>[Look inside, too!](http://mysefer.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=624.jpg)</sub>

Comment: Not only "out of stock" but it's also out of print. You'll most likely have a difficult time finding it new or online.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've seen the snippet view here: https://books.google.ca/books?id=AU4RAQAAIAAJ&q=ישראל&source=gbs_word_cloud_r&cad=4

Comment: Though this should qualify as an answer I'd rather post as a comment: I'd suggest contacting Moznaim bookstore; IIRC they were the publishing company. Haven't seen that sefer in years, and even back then only in 2 different libraries; no stores.

Comment: @oliver do you know of anyone actually ever owning it? :)

Comment: @Shmuel Privately owned? Nopes, none that I recall. But again, worth checking Moznaim. IIRC the book was printed posthumously and they had the "jurisdiction" over R. Kaplan's manuscripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's now available at [hebrewbooks.org/61862](https://hebrewbooks.org/61862).
It's also available in scanned PDF [here](https://docdro.id/u73eqeo).

Comment: Something spammy/phishy going on with that pdf download....

Answer (score 7):

It seems to exist in [4 libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/sefer-moreh-or-al-ha-inyanim-ha-kashim-ba-hashkafah-takhlit-ha-beriah-tsimtsum-yediah-u-vehirah/oclc/123233712):

1. Jewish Theological Seminary of America
2. [Yeshiva University](http://yulib.mc.yu.edu:8001/lib/item?id=chamo:173212&theme=YULIS) in Gottesman, level 5A
3. Princeton University Library
4. [Stanford University Libraries](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/?q=123233712) in SAL3

Comment: Your answer may no longer apply.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen it Tuvias in Monsey 845-426-0824 before the move. I believe I bought my copy at mekor haseforim 718-627-4385 in Flatbush. also I would try pinters used seforim (718) 871-2260 then the king of seforim beigelisons (718) 436-1165 and seforim world (718) 438-8414

Comment: Tuvia's website claims they don't have it - https://www.monseyjudaica.com/?s=%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94+%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8&post_type=product&x=0&y=0

Comment: https://www.manta.com/c/mmgn7yv/mekor-hasfarim-inc says the web site of _mekor haseforim_ is www.mekorjudaica.com which claims not to have it: https://mekorjudaica.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94+%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8

Comment: I would be happy to send you a copy via email 5581639@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try a used book store. There's one between 31and 32 3114 Quentin Avenue Brooklyn, NY called the Mizrachi book store which might have it. Give them a call maybe.

Comment: Google has the address as 3114 Quentin Rd.

Comment: @alex yeah it's actually between 31st and 32nd.I'll edit in the exact address

Answer (score 0):

[Nehora](https://www.nehora.com/) is an online - well, it’s basically eBay for Sefarim. They seem to [have it in stock](https://www.nehora.com/products/Moreh-Ohr-%252d-Rabbi-Aryeh-Kaplan-----%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%252d%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%9F%252d%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8%252d%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%94.html). I can’t guarantee that it’ll still be in stock by the time you see this - sefarim tend to go quickly on that site!

Comment: Hi DonielF, my experience with nehora was that although this book is listed, since there is no add to cart button on it (like normal books have) it does not allow you to purchase it due to it not being available. Then again, I hope to be proven wrong.

Comment: @Shmuel- correct - it says: Availability: Out of Print