# Sefarim on sci-fi/fantasy theoretical Halachic questions

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation

Here on Mi Yodeya we have a [long and extensive (and growing!) list of sci-fi and fantasy questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3744/).

Have there been any Rabbanim who have written complete Sefarim on these kinds of topics?

Comment: Do they have to be Rabbonim? We have a Mi Yodeya user who has been working on a hilchos Star Trek sefer for a few years now.

Comment: Does https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/871723724 count?

Comment: @msh210 I guess *technically* it does, but I'm not sure if we should be publicizing books by someone put in Cherem (though, admittedly, it wasn't for this book in particular).

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to find such information would be to read the sources cited in the answers to those questions.

I cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43835/is-there-any-reason-to-deny-aliens/97142?r=SearchResults#97142) a section of the [Sefer Moreh Ohr](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92582/where-can-i-get-aryeh-kaplan-s-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8) by [Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Kaplan)  who wrote about the topic of aliens.

The entire essay appears on pp. 47-50 in Moreh Ohr. This is the end which I have translated:

> We see from this [starting on p. 47] that there is a singular species in the world that is capable of free will, Torah, reward and punishment which are the purpose of creation. This is mankind, to whom God has given The One Torah. It is however possible that there exists many species of living creatures on other stars i.e. planets, which may even be capable of intelligence and wisdom, just not freewill. The subject of freewill is but a very small item as it is, that cannot be verified in science [or by scientists], only by belief in our Torah. And if they do find additional species of living creatures, we have already learned from the Torah that don't have freewill.

Comment: I’m not looking for individual pieces, but rather complete Sefarim.

Comment: Ah your question was perhaps slightly vague in that regard

Comment: I’m not sure what’s vague about “who have written Sefarim on these kinds of topics,” rather than simply “who have written about these kinds of topics.” I can edit to further clarify if you think it’s necessary.