# Other species in deep space and the Uniqueness of Klal Yisrael

Tags: torah-study, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, outer-space

The sheer vastness of space [almost mathematically guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation?wprov=sfti1) that there are other species or advanced civilizations in other galaxies or solar systems.

How do we reconcile this with the [uniqueness of the Jewish People](https://www.aish.com/jl/jnj/jn/48939317.html) -  and the specific mission that G-d has granted the Jewish people by the giving of the Torah.

Comment: Although note the [Fermi Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) (G-d is perfectly capable of creating a Great Filter, should He so desire)

Comment: The numerous questions regarding aliens on this site don't satisfy your question here?

Comment: @user6591 I didn’t see any that answer this specific question

Comment: Um, there are "other species or advanced civilizations" right here on Earth, too. Why ask about extraterrestrial ones?

Comment: @msh210 good question. I would presume that one could say that revelation accounts for them too - for them to either be witness to the messiahs redemption. But for Hashem to have created an entire other world and civilazation outside of the Jewish purview - how do we understand that

Comment: This https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43835/is-there-any-reason-to-deny-aliens-according-to-Judaism is relevant and may even be effectively a dup.

Comment: This comment comes from https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43835/is-there-any-reason-to-deny-aliens-according-to-judaism "I realize you are asking for proof of negation, but I will just mention that in the book Thinking aloud, Rav Soloveitchik is recorded as saying alien life is definitely possible and ** that there may even be an Am Hanivchor for that planet!**  user6591 Jul 25 '14 at 1:58" {my emphasis}

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok Thanks! I was looking where I wrote that and I couldn't find it:)

Comment: Why so many downvotes? How can we be the light unto the nations that are light years away?

Comment: Think about the phrase "almost mathematically guarantees". What does it mean? Maybe almost -  but not quite.

Comment: Rav meir mazuz proves through multiple sources that Aliens don't exist. I heard in a shiur that according to the Zohar the earth is hollow and contains other unknown legendary species, is it possible to wager that the greys are one of them?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97142/16706

Comment: Space is very small relative to the probability of the existence of life.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE can you elaborate what you mean

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv The observable universe is a sphere with a diameter of about 8.8×10^26 meters. Let's cube this to get a volume of approx.  10^78 cubic meters. The probability of even one primary protein structure developing by chance (according to the Union of Orthodox Jewish Scientists) is in the region of 1/2^200. So 10^78 / 2^200 =   622 thousand million million cubic meters, which is the volume of a sphere with radius approx 500 kms. That means that the conceptual size of the universe relative to this event is approx. 500 kms which is insufficient to blow my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[R. Joseph B. Soloveitchik](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) addressed this point when asked about alien life by R. David Holzer.

**The Rav Thinking Aloud p. 93**

> *[DH:] Would the discovery of alien life be an issue in terms of the Torah view?*
>
> It is possible that *Hashem* created other life forms on other planets. It is no problem to *yahadus*. The reason man likes to think he is the only created being in the entire universe is because of his egotistical nature.
>
> Even the concept of *am ha’nivchar* may only be relative to our world, our small section of the universe. The *Torah* is written from the viewpoint of our sun, moon, and stars. It would not detract from our being the *am ha’nivchar* of this region of space if there were other *am ha’nivchar* in a distant galaxy.

Comment: Same here,had this in mind when I saw the question.

Comment: I don't understand the context in which this was said, if any

Answer (score 3):

Mathematical likelihood has no bearing or evidence  about  what Hashem  did or did not create .

Rav Yaakov Kaminetsky   said that there may or may not be living creature (animals) in out of space but there absolutly are no human like creatures with Bechira (free will) because Hasehm would not have created  creatures with Bechira without Torah to guide them and the Torah given to  Klal Yisroel on this planet is the ONLY Torah.

Zos HaTorah Lo Tihay Muchlefes.

Comment: Maybe they just haven't gotten Torah yet. American Indians also didn't have torah for some time

Comment: @DoubleAA How do you know that? According to Rav Azaria de Rossi, and several other sources I've seen, when the Tanakh mentions Ofir it means the New World. And indeed more and more evidence is coming up that ancient civilazations from the New and Old worlds did in fact have contact with each other for millennias. For an example, Pharaoh Ramses II was found to contain traces of Tobacco and cocao in his body cells

Comment: @Adam [Your last two sentences are most likely incorrect.](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/4t6htu/was_there_tobacco_in_eurasia_before_the_columbian/d5fckte/) AFAIK, there's no evidence of ancient New/Old World trade routes.

Comment: is there a source for this statement of Rav Kaminetsky? (Is he cited anywhere, did he write this, etc.)

Comment: Rav Kaminetsky having said this is quoted by many Talmidim in general. I heard it in his name from Rav Yisroel Belsky It it also in B'Mechitzos Rabbinu .

Comment: And some people like the ones on Sentinel Island still don't have it @DoubleAA

Comment: @Heshy I guess they don't have free will on sentinel island

Comment: Not sure why my comment was deleted, but reddit isn't reliable. Use a real source next time

Answer (score 0):

If there are sentient beings on other worlds, and they are NOT the descendants of human beings from Earth, it would invalidate a key teaching in the Talmud [Sanhedrin 37a, 38a]:

> -Why did God start humanity by creating only ONE man?
>
> -So that unbelievers would not be able to say: There are many authorities in Heaven, and each created a different person.
>
> -So that no one should be able to tell his neighbor, “My ancestors were better than your ancestors”.
>
> -So the wicked could not say: “We are children of the wicked, so we cannot change our ways.”
>
> -So the feeling of fraternity among people will limit crime.
>
> -So people would know that God is One: Even though God created people in His image, every person can still be different from every other person:  Unity in diversity.
>
> -So that people would know that he who destroys one life is as if he had destroyed an entire world, and he who saves one life is as if he had saved an entire world.

Comment: So you’re saying it WOULD be an issue?

Comment: In the sense that these teachings would no longer be valid.  But it's still possible.