# Did King Solomon create the first train?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, king-solomon

I once heard from a Rabbi in a Nach lesson that King Solomon made the first train, however, the Rabbi cannot remember where the exact source.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Prob. referring to R. [Yosef Hayyim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Hayyim)’s novel interpretation in his Benayahu on Gittin (IIRC, 68a). (FTR, “steam locomotive” might be more accurate, following his piece.)

Comment: You beat me to it Oliver :) Check the Artscroll Gittin on 68a in the footnotes (#13) who brings the Benayahu as Oliver said: "See Benayahu who suggests that Solomon had discovered certain principles of modern science ....was able to build himself a motorized coach."

Comment: Related not-yet-answered question: [What technology did King Solomon have?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/what-technology-did-king-solomon-have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ben Yehoyada (on "shiddim v'shiddos, Koheles) says that Shlomo built himself trains that went so fast as to seem demonic (hence "shiddim").

Comment: Do you mean to Gittin 68a, where this passuk is quoted? I didn’t think Ben Yehoyada commented on Tanach.

Comment: Can you link to where he actually said this?