Aliens and Ever Min Hachai
According to Halacha, does the prohibition of Ever Min Hachai apply to alien life, or only species of animals on earth? I believe it would likely apply to aliens, but since all Halacha of kashrut were in a context where only life on earth was known, I don’t know if the Psak is definitely the same for alien species.

Question not not applicable as there are no aliens.

@GershonGold you don't seem to understand the point of this website. It is not for questions that ask for a practical psak but to discuss Torah subjects including theoretical ones as well.

Can you give a reason for why an animal from another planet should have a different rule applied to it?

What if aliens don't sweat?

@Gershon https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9197/does-the-torah-discuss-aliens#9203

@Dude with all due respect Gershon is the highest-ranked member of MiYodeya - I would guess he understands the site...

@GershonGold דווקא because you're the highest-ranking member here and one of the longest-running I find your comment surprising. Not only have we had other alien-related questions in the past, besides other completely hypothetical ones, but there's no clear proof that there isn't alien life out there.

@GershonGold what's your source? Sefer habris maamer 3 chapter 4 explicitly says there are

@Dude lol Gershon is literally the #1 user here, how can he not know the point of the website lol (also he used a double negative so what's the issue). I have a bigger question for him though - how does he know there aren't aliens? I think there are a lot of people who would love to know

@B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem "explicitly says there are" ? https://shulchanaruchharav.com/does-life-exist-on-other-planets-what-is-the-torahs-perspective/

@RabbiKaii I read the link, as well as the original source, and the sicha from Parshas Devarim 5729, printed in Sefer hasichos page 341 (parts 6, 7, 9 and 10) and yes it does say that there are. The sicha implies it's some kind of human like creatures ("mentshin")

@RabbiKaii that's not a valid argument and point of his comment is wrong

The Rambam states in Ma'achalot Asssuros 5:1

מפי השמועה למדו שזה שנאמר בתורה לא תאכל הנפש עם הבשר לאסור אבר שנחתך
מן החי. ועל אבר מן החי הוא אומר לנח אך בשר בנפשו דמו לא תאכלו. ואיסור
אבר מן החי נוהג בבהמה חיה ועוף בטהורים אבל לא בטמאים:

That Ever min hachai does not apply to non-kosher animals, so I suppose it might depend on whether the Alien is Kosher?
Also the Rambam points out it applies to Domesticated/Wild animals and birds. Perhaps this excludes Aliens or perhaps it is just meant to exclude fish. Similarly maybe Kashrus is only a requirement for animals from Earth?
Until further notice I'll assume the Rambam holds it does not apply to non-Kosher aliens.
